# Environmental Variables in Fission

Tags: kubernetes-fission

Is there a way to set environment variables in fission? I can't seem to find anything on their documentation and do not want to put credentials in the codebase.

I wasn't sure if it would make sense to add it as a build variable but don't know how that would work with the cli.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know of the support for environment variables is being worked on.
The relevant PR: https://github.com/fission/fission/pull/399

As a temporary workaround you could inject environment variables using a custom Fission environment. For example with the python environment:

```
FROM fission/python-env

ENV DB_CREDENTIALS=foobar

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["server.py"]
```

Note that any function using the custom environment will have access to the environment variable(!)

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to store the credentials would be storing them in the K8S cluster in ConfigMap resources and the accessing the in our code.
You can follow [this](https://docs.fission.io/0.12.0/usage/access-secret-cfgmap-in-function/#accessing-secrets-and-configmaps) link to read more about how to access the configmap from fission code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this By setting up a function yaml-spec

```yaml
apiVersion: fission.io/v1
kind: Environment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: func-name
spec:
  builder:
    command: build
    container:
      name: ""
      resources: {}
    image: fission/python-builder
  imagepullsecret: myregistrykey
  keeparchive: false
  poolsize: 3
  resources: {}
  runtime:
    podspec:
      containers:
      - name: container-name
        env: # here !!!!!!!!!!!!
        - name: value1
          value: 1
        - name: value2
          value: 2
        resources: {}
    image: addr_of_image
  version: 2
```

please read: https://doc.crds.dev/github.com/fission/fission